# mysql query consumes long time on database and works fine on other

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, indexing

I am executing this query to get the number of products for each category on my website

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total
    FROM  category_path cp
    LEFT JOIN  product_to_category p2c  ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)
    LEFT JOIN  product p  ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)
    LEFT JOIN  product_description pd  ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)
    LEFT JOIN  product_to_store p2s  ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id)
    WHERE  pd.language_id = '1'
      AND  p.status = '1'
      AND  p.date_available <= NOW()
      AND  p2s.store_id = '0'
      AND  cp.path_id = '20'
      AND  p.is_family ='1';
```

On my local machine it works fine and returns the result within .02

```
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|   392 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)`
```

but when I execute the same query on my server's DB it takes a lot

```
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|   412 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.78 sec)
```

I searched for any possible solution but I didn't find, If anyone can help me to find the reason I will appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with **Indexing** the Columns

Example -:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `product_id` (`product_id`);
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `language_id` (`language_id`);
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `status` (`status`);
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `date_available` (`date_available`);
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `store_id` (`store_id`);
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `path_id` (`path_id`);
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `is_family` (`is_family`);
```

Comment: When appropriate, 'composite' indexes are better than single-column indexes.

Comment: Do not index "flag" by themselves.  They are rarely useful.

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use `LEFT` unless you need it.  It may inhibit optimizations.
- Are you using the same version on both machines?
- p2c and p2s smell like a many:many mapping tables.  If so, see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for tips on optimizing.
- `p` needs the composite `INDEX(is_family, status, date_available)`

Comment: thank you for your notes, but since I am using the same version, how the execution time for the same query will vary in this way, it was taking around 20 sec to load any page but after I indexed the important columns it worked fine?

Comment: Similar number of rows in the tables?  Same value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?